# Как в питоне добавлять элемент в список когда я его создаю с помощью random.choice и принчу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, случайные-числа, append

Как в питоне добавлять элемент в список когда я его создаю с помощью `random.choice` и причину?

Например, я делаю так:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
other_numbers = []
print(other_numbers.append(ramdom.choice(numbers)))
```

Оно возвращает `None`.

Так вот как мне сделать так чтобы я и запринтил этот элемент и добавил его в список

Comment: Мне нужно вывести табличку рандомных букв и затем сравнивать эти буквы с таблички с другими списками слов, если есть альтернативный вариант как это сделать, я буду очень рад его выслушать))

Comment: None возвращает метод `append`. В переменную кладете результат `choice`, принтите переменную и добавляете ее в список

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант выглядит вот так:

```
import random
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
other_numbers = []
r_number = random.choice(numbers)
other_numbers.append(r_number)
print(r_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сначала сохранить сгенерированный элемент в переменную. А потом можно отдельными действиями зааппендить этот элемент, а потом напечатать:

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
other_numbers = []

elem = random.choice(numbers)

other_numbers.append(elem)
print(elem)
```